# how to find number of sides of an irregular polygon?

Tags: geometry

An irregular polygon has one angle 126 degrees and the rest 162 degrees. how many sides are there in this irregular polygon?

I have tried to find our the sides with the formula of a regular polygon; obviously it doesn't work.

Comment: It seems like there should be more information on this problem...

Answer (score 5):

Using the formula of the sum of interior angles

$$162(n-1) + 126 = 180(n-2) \Rightarrow n=18. $$

**Remark:** I assume a simple and plane polygon.

Comment: So, we assume it is a simple, closed, polygon...

Comment: I assume that. Actually, I think it is exactly what has been asked.

Comment: Also, we assume it is a plane polygon.

Comment: @GEdgar, Yes, I suppose the classical definition of polygons.

Answer (score -1):

Sum of exterior angle of  polygon $= 360$.

$180-126= 54$

$54+ (180-162)n=360$

$18n=306$

$n=17$ (number of sides measuring $162^\circ$) $+1$ (side measuring $126^\circ$) $=18$ sides.

Comment: We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Answer (score -4):

try this: do the average of 162 and 126. So that would equal 144. Then subtract 180- 144 and you will get 36. Then divide 36 by 360 and get 10. Therefore your polygon has 10 sides.

Comment: might be good to justify why do you do those operations.